# OnActivated is only working when new tab opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to communicate with the content script of the tab that has just been switched to using message passing. Here is my code in the background.js script.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeInfo.tabId, { greeting: "hello" }, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });
});
```

And here is my code in my content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({ farewell: "goodbye" });
    loadContent();
});
```

Is the content script no longer listening in an inactive tab even when it's switched back to that tab? Why does this only run in a newly opened tab?

To further clarify why I want to do this, sometimes tabs are left open without reloading, and my script has already been executed. When information pertaining to the script changes using the popup options, I want the content to reload on tab change, and a particular function to run again without reloading the page. Therefore, injecting the content script is less than ideal since it's already been executed.

Comment: As for "it's switched back to that tab", is the content script injected in that tab before? I mean after you load the extension, have you ever reload the previously opened tabs to ensure your content scripts are injected?

Comment: You have a valid point. Ha. I was going back to tabs with older versions of the content script. I can't believe that was the solution. Thank you. Besides what is possibly magic, how did you conclude it might be that?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-chrome-extension/2850/content-scripts#t=201608010722142170944), it's a often-asked question and Xan has mentioned this trick in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**background.js**

```
        chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {

            chrome.tabs.query({
                active: true,
                currentWindow: true
            }, function(tabs) {

                 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeInfo.tabId, 
                  { greeting: "hello" }, function(response) {
                    console.log(response.farewell);
               });
            });

        });
```